# Apple Sample Code : Multiple Detail Views

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I just downloaded the apple same code Multiple Detail Views.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html

I was playing around with it to try and figure out how it works, and so far I have only had one problem:  when I create my own files/view, there Menu button is not present.

[image: Default first view controller with Menu button]
Default first view controller with Menu button

[image: The drop down menu with the third view that I created]
The drop down menu with the third view that I created

[image: The third view that I created, that has no menu button]
The third view that I created, that has no menu button

I poked around the interface builder and there are no buttons there for the default views.  Then I found a method in the RootViewController that displays the button.

My problem is that I can't find where the first 2 views call that method to display that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

In the end, all you have to do is link the view, and the toolbar to the file's owner.  You can view a tutorial on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368581/set-up-a-basic-split-view-based-application/11368582#11368582) (in part 3c)